# StringBuilder namespace, c#, visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, stringbuilder

What namespace does `StringBuilder` belong to?

I typed:

```
using System.Text.StringBuilder;
```

But the intellisense, won't let me type `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I really think we should do some researches about our problems before asking it on stackoverflow, this way we can learn better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its very easy to determine in which namespace .NET class lives. you have two ways:

1. Find interesting class in MSDN and in `Inheritance Hierarchy` section you can see **FULL** class name. Full class name means that before class name would be its namespace. For StringBuilder full class name would face as `System.Text.StringBuilder`. Just omit class name (StringBuilder) and you get namespace
2. Open Object browser in VS and search for interesting class. In results, click on the class and in detail view interesting information will appear:
   [image]

I always use second way, because its more easy for me.

Answer (score 7):

`using` [directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) "import" namespaces, so it should read `using System.Text;`

Answer (score 4):

It's in the System.Text namespace.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5(v=VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

If you're ever unsure what namespace something is in, type it into the editor (e.g. **StringBuilder**) and hit **Ctrl .** (control dot) to bring up the possible namespaces.

VS2010 will then insert a using declaration into the file for you.

Comment: The editor is the window where you normally write your code. If you managed to type any code at all, and saw the syntax highlighter coloring the code for you, and tried to interact with Intellisense, then you are already using it.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `.StringBuilder` in your using directive.
StringBuilder is the class itsself.

Comment: Nitpick - it's a using *directive*, not a using *statement*. A using *statement* is one which disposes of resources at the end of its body. Just being a terminology pedant as normal :)

Answer (score 2):

The namespace is `System.Text`, not  System.Text.StringBuilder

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can just type `StringBuilder`, right click it, and choose "Resolve >". This way you can import the right namespace without knowing the name. You'd have to type the class name correctly though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the .dll file added as a reference (and for something as basic as that, you have the reference), simply write StringBuilder (case-sensative) and hit Alt+Shift+F12 (or mouse over the small arrow near it) and you'll see a list of possible solutions, one of them will be to automatically add the correct using, which, in this case is:

```
using System.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

Namespace StringBuilder belong to - System.Text;